# Get min and max time section

Tags: mysql

have table
[image: similar this]

I want get min and max time section for each day,
[image: as this]

thanks

Comment: please create an SQLFiddle

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get an (useful) answer. And don't use images when a simple copy-paste of text provides the same information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select date(event_start), min(time(event_start)), max(time(event_start)) from t
group by date(event_start)
order by date(event_start)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `CAST()`.

**Query**

```
select cast(event_start as date) `date`,
min(cast(event_start as time)) `min_time`,
max(cast(event_start as time)) `max_time`
from `your_table_name`
group by cast(event_start as date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**<kbd>[Rexter Sample](http://rextester.com/BPI25600)</kbd>**

```
select DATE_FORMAT(event_start, '%Y-%m-%d') as date1
,min(DATE_FORMAT(event_start,'%H:%i:%s')) as min1
,max(DATE_FORMAT(event_start,'%H:%i:%s')) as max1
from your_table
group by DATE_FORMAT(event_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
```